# What function to use to update an odoo field without replacing the existing line

Tags: python, xml, linux, odoo

I'm working on odoo version 10.
I have a recording that lists the students enrolled in a school.
I want to automate the change of school year and classes at the end of the school year by clicking a button.
When I click a button to update, I want to keep the history of the previous year and automatically fill a new line in the table by schoolchildren.

I am a beginner and I need help with the creation of the function.

Today I have a view that works. I created the update button and I know how to create a function from the name of the button.
I still have to create the function in Python but I'm lost on the way to do.

Can you enlighten me?

I can not update a colony (school_name) with the write () function. Maybe I'm using it badly? or maybe this is not the function to use here?

Here is my Python code for the button:

```
@api.multi
def button_for_run_update(self):
    self.write({'school_name': "Test"})
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Do you get an Error? Could you please provide your view definition? My first guess: You forgot to add `type="object"` in your button definition.

Comment: Thanks for this first response.
No I do not have an error is I add the object type on my button.

Here is the code of the view that includes the update button:

<button style="margin-left:75%;" name="button_for_run_update" type="object"
                                    class="btn btn-info" string="Mise à jour"
                                    confirm="Vous êtes sûr de votre choix ?"/>

Comment: The button works because I was trying to refer to another view and it worked. But my problem in this case is the write() function that does not work.

Comment: update the question with error log

Comment: But does odoo run your method when clicking the button? Did you try to change other field? Maybe 'school_name' it is computed or related?

Comment: I just corrected to do a test. My write () function now works but that's not what I want to do. I do not want to replace a field of a line but add a new line. What function do I have to use? Thank you

@api.multi
def button_for_run_update(self):
    self.write({'name': "Test"})

Comment: Please help me for my problem :) I don't find the function :/